# Using wildcard in migration tool package xml

Tags: migration, search, pattern

I know how to use  tags for one object example: "Account_History__c". But I am looking for a way to select all objects that start with a specific pattern.

In our org we prefix all objects with the project prefix example Project1_DashboardUsers__c, Project1_AppOwner__c etc. I want to specify this in package.xml  like -

Project1*
  CustomMetadata

Can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No. The only wildcard supported is the literal `*`, which matches *everything*. Of course, not all objects support the wildcard, so you need to check the manual. Personally, I'd recommend using a package (Setup > Create > Packages). You can add all the components you want, and it will automatically add dependencies for you, and then you can retrieve the package using [RetrieveRequest's packageNames](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve_request.htm#field_packageNames) attribute. This will automatically include a package.xml file in the response that you can use for deployment directly.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. The create-package has taken me to the next step. However it is also bringing in the dependencies. Is there a way to ignore the dependencies? For example I am making change to Project1_Class1. However Project2_Page_Layout2 is using this class. I dont want to deploy this page layout in my deployment since Project2's deployment is handled by a different team. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Wildcards pull down all metadata of a specific type when referenced in package.xml files.  You cant use them to do more specific filtering.

However, [ASIDE.IO](https://www.aside.io/login) does allow you to perform retrieves and create package XML files based on queries, which enables the type of functionality you are describing.  Once you are logged into ASIDE, click the **push** button, then choose **Select a Filter** > **Create new Filter** > **Add Filter**.  From here you are able to couple multiple queries together to create a dynamic retrieval filter.  For your example you could add the following queries:

`SELECT stuff FROM CustomObject WHERE DeveloperName like 'Project1%'`

`SELECT stuff FROM ApexClass WHERE Name like 'Project1%'`

Then you are able to save this retrieve filter and use it to seed retrieves and the creation of package.xml files.